# Remove any blank or whitespaced lines using regex

Tags: regex, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I am trying to find and remove any blank or whitespaced lines in OpenOffice document using regex.

Currently I can do it in two steps:

1. Search for `^$` and replace with nothing.

   This will remove any empty lines.
2. Search for `^\s*$` and replace with nothing.

   This will remove any lines which contains only spaces or tabs.

   **Important note:** From my point of view, this 2nd version should also remove any empty lines (as 1st version), but actually it doesn't.

So, there are actually two questions.

- For what reason second regex matches only lines with spaces and tabs, but don't match empty lines?
- Is there way to combine first and second version to achieve desired result in one step? Here what I tried: `^$|^\s*$` and `(^|^\s*)$`. But it doesn't work. It matches only whitespaced lines, but not empty ones.

Text for test:

```
Just for example, I changed spaces to dots
and tabs to dashes.


aa

..........................

-------------------

aaaaaaaaaaaaaa

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Desired result:

```
aa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: According to https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions, `|` is for finding multiple terms.  `^$` is an expression rather than a term, so that may be why it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AltSearch](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/alternative-dialog-find-replace-writer-altsearch) can do this as a single step using a Batch script.  In the AltSearch dialog, click on `Batch >>`.  Then `Edit` the file and paste the following code at the end.

```
[Name] Remove any blank or whitespaced lines

  ; Remove any lines which contains only spaces or tabs.
  [Find]^\s*$
  [Replace]
  [Parameters] MsgOff Regular 
  [Command] ReplaceAll  

  ; Remove any empty lines.
  [Find]^$
  [Replace]
  [Parameters] MsgOff Regular 
  [Command] ReplaceAll

[End]
```

Now, save the text file and click `Refresh`.  Finally, click on `Remove any blank or whitespaced lines` and press `Execute`.

This produces the desired result and shows a single dialog:

```
Batch   'Remove any blank or whitespaced lines'   is ended. 

10  replacements have been done.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the title of your question reads like asking for a pure regex (which is why I found it):

```
\s(?=\s)
```

Simply replace its matches with nothing - see [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hcYvCq/1) and [Regexr](https://regexr.com/45tv6).